# ora-01722 - i know what is means but its still not the problem

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data from an old table to a new one but i have a error ora-01722

I try to do:   `to_number(trav_no)`  because in the old table `trav_no` is varchar and in the new one its `number(3,0)`

What should I do?

```
Select trav_no,
       edit_cod,
       amount,
       user_id
from t1;

insert into t2 (trip_id, type_id,f_amount, upd_by)
select to_number(trav_no),
       to_number(edit_cod),
       amount,
       user_id
from t1;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and explain what you want to do when the string cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: If you get an error please post the error *message*, no one knows all error codes of all systems by heart.

Comment: ora-01722 invalid number

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, your old table contains values that cannot be converted to a number. You need to identfiy the affected rows to either manually fix those values or exclude them in your INSERT statement.

The easiest way to identify them is to select them using regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(trav_no, '^[0-9]+$')
   OR NOT REGEXP_LIKE(edit_cod, '^[0-9]+$');
```

The query assumes that the numbers must be positive integer numbers. If not, refine the regular expression accordingly.

Comment: This regex applies only for positive integer numbers. Do you have any other valid numbers, e.g. `1.0` or `-3`, etc.?

Comment: I have already stated that it only works for positive integer numbers. It seems a reasonable restriction as the column names indicate that the columns contain an ID or serial number, but not an amount.